# .htaccess mod_rewrite to create clean URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a data driven site that passes information to determine what the next page should show using the $_GET parameter.

I want the URL's to look nicer and be structured simply.

I have been reading about mod_rewrite but so far failed to implement it.

```
<?php $post = $_GET['ID']; ?>
<?php $loca = $_GET['loca']; ?>
```

This is taken from the URL to work out what table we want and what post ID. The URL at the moment is `index.php?ID=4&loca=Pages`

How would I make this work if it were instead. `/pages/(the name column of the post of this ID)`.

Comment: I recommend keeping the id in the url somewhere (just like Stack Overflow does): /pages/id/(The name)

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Also [What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/(\d+)/ /index.php?ID=$1&loca=pages
```

It rewrites any url starting with `pages/(some number)/` to the result. You should probably add some server side logic as well to do a 302 redirect if the url isn't exactly `/pages/id/(Name that matches id)/`. You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the string and then compare it to the string that it should be and do a redirect if it doesn't match.

Just like if you go to: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057691/This+is+not+the+title`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057691/This+is+not+the+title)

You get redirected to the version with the correct title. You should also update the links you have around your site to use the new url format.

Answer (score 0):

There are *a lot* of examples of how to do this on google.

Tutorial: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html